# Question regarding Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

While reading a theorem on Galois theory I came up with this statement "Let $E/F$ be a finite separable extension. Then $E$ is contained in an extension of $K$ which is Galois over $F$.

Now my question is about first statement. Because according as what I know if$E/F$ is a finite extension then it's an algebraic extension and as it's separable hence it's a normal extension also. So $E/F$ is normal separable extension, hence it is Galois. So what am I thinking wrong. It will be really great if you can help me with it

Comment: not every separable extension is normal.

Comment: I know not every separable extension isn't normal. But isn't every separable finite extension normal. As even finite extension is algebric.

Comment: not every separable finite extension is normal.

Comment: It will be great if u can  give an example

Comment: I think I have an answer should I post it here

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt[3]5\,)\supset\Bbb Q$